# Spring - Jackson request mapping with validation. Throws "HttpMessageNotReadableException" when string given for long property

Tags: spring, validation, data-binding, binding, mapping

I'm trying to use @RequestBody @Valid annotations to bean validation and data mapping in Spring.

As you can see in entity bean, I'm using @NotNull and @Min annotations, both of them are using different validation message and I can read this messages in controller at **BindingResult** argument.

But, when client sent *String* value instead of *long* for "operatorId" field, I'm getting an error you can see it bellow.

**My question is :**

When client sets a non-numeric string value for operatorId, I want to return an error message text to client. (ex: "You should sent a numeric value etc.")

**Entity Bean :**

```
@Entity(name="ua")
@Table(name="ua")
public class UserAgreement extends BaseContractEntity {

    @Column(name = "OPERATOR_ID")
    @NotNull(message = "operatorId must be provided")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "operatorId must be bigger then zero")
    protected long operatorId;


    //... getters setters, etc
}
```

**Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ug", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ServiceResponse saveUserAgreement(@RequestBody @Valid UserAgreement userAgreement,
                                     BindingResult result) {

    ServiceResponse serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse();

    if(result.hasErrors()) {

        serviceResponse.setMessage(result.getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());
        serviceResponse.setErrorCode("400");
        return serviceResponse;

    } else {

        // call service
        serviceResponse.setMessage("ok");
        return serviceResponse;
    }
}
```

**This is my example request :**

When make a POST request with this json text (**wrong operatorId non-numeric value !**) :

```
{"content":"text content text","announcement":"YES","approved":"YES","operatorId":"5fg0"}
```

Getting this error :

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of long from String value '5fg0': not a valid Long value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@9ba3afe; line: 1, column: 69] (through reference chain: com.ggg.agr.core.model.UserAgreement["operatorId"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of long from String value '5fg0': not a valid Long value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@9ba3afe; line: 1, column: 69] (through reference chain: com.ggg.agr.core.model.UserAgreement["operatorId"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of long from String value '5fg0': not a valid Long value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@9ba3afe; line: 1, column: 69] (through reference chain: com.ggg.agr.core.model.UserAgreement["operatorId"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.weirdStringException(StdDeserializationContext.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseLong(StdDeserializer.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$LongDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:846)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$LongDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:833)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:166)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Are you sending request type as "application/json"..?

Comment: Yes, It's working without exception when I sent correct json document.

for ex:

`{"content":"text content text","announcement":"YES","approved":"YES","operatorId":"6"}`

with this request body, it working perfect.

The problem occur when I set `"operatorId":"any_string"`

Comment: I'm having the same question. Did you solve this eventually? Spring @RequestBody bindings seem not to be really useful...

Comment: @rossen-stoyanchev 's answer is works correct. I was add ExceptionHandler annotation method to controller to handle Type conversion errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's important to understand that first Jackson deserializes the JSON content of the request body and creates a UserAgreement object. Only then can standard bean validation be applied as a result of the @Valid annotation. So you can think of @Valid as an added layer of validation only after JSON deserialization succeeds. Use an @ExceptionHandler method for deserialization errors.